# iPhone POST JSON to PHP expecting return for login/receiving data

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

OK, I am quite new to this Objective-C and JSON thing, so please bare with my questions. I am using Stig Json Framework and ASIHTTPRequest.

My overall objective is to send JSON data (containing login credential) to a PHP webservice and expecting a return once the PHP process the data. I need an authorize key from the return and also specific user data tied to the login credential.

Now, I can send the JSON data via POST all right, consume the data via PHP all right. But I just don't understand the logic of the return data, as I said earlier. I only know that ASIHTTPRequest do return the *response string* via anything echo'ed from the PHP, but is this the correct way to get the return data I want?

Or, do I encode it back to JSON? How?

I think another viable solution is to write a webservice that receive parameters via URL and return JSON data. For example, how do I write `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@<name>`?

Comment: JSON is the transfer medium. You'd decode the received JSON text into a native data structure, whatever that happens to be in obj-c/xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is returned as a JSON string and you need to convert it to Objective-C object using the "`JSONValue`" method before working with the returned data.

For example:

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
```

Now you can work with the returned data as an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I've tried this , my JSON responseString will be string(x) "{"a":1 , "b":2}" instead of {"a":1 , "b":2} requested from a .json file . How do I work with the former ?

Comment: It looks like a PHP problem because your PHP code is not returning proper JSON.  How are you encoding and returning data from PHP?

Comment: I got the string correctly after setting json header for the echoed string . Now I got it to work with the NSDictionary already , which I can't previously .

Comment: Finally , is this way normally how others pass and receive JSON from iphone to the webservices ?

Comment: Yes, this is very common as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can `json_encode` data from PHP and echo that. Now you will receive JSON data in the ASIHTTPRequest delegate method, that is, a response string. Then use it as you like.

Remember to set the header type to `json` while you echo data from PHP.

Comment: where do I set the header type ? By just adding this line to the php ? header('Content-type: application/json'); ?

Comment: ya you are right , I have to set the header type . No wonder why I couldn't serialize the string properly , thanks !